VBA Error msg "This method cannot be called after the send method has been called"
I have couple of line codes of VBA and when running the code I get the Run-time error
'-2147024891 (80070005)' : Access is denied. When I click on debug, the error is on the code line XMLPage.send with the error message pop-up: Run-time error '-1072954816 (c00c0240)': This method cannot be called after the send method has been called.
My code is below:
Sub BrowseToExchangeRatesWithQueryStringAndXML()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://x-rates.com/table/?from=GBP&amount=3", False 
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
End Sub

Thank you.
I searched for other questions on this matter but they seem to not be relating to my problem.

Yes, it worked when I changed to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60. Thank you for showing me the other post.

Hi NickSlash. Yes, I changed to the ServerXMLHTTP60 object in the MSXML2 library and the error disappeared. Thanks
